# Angular-how to use OAuth2 token for further http Rest Api call with springboot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

After successful Oauth2 (google auth), angular app receive token generated from sprinfboot server in redirect url. How to use this token for further rest api call to springboot?

Comment: Did you read https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749 ? If not, start there and then ask more specific questions if you're still getting stuck

Answer (score 0):

How create new secure request against Oauth2 server find here: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/making-authenticated-requests/

For your question is important this part:

```
POST /resource/1/update HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer RsT5OjbzRn430zqMLgV3Ia"
Host: api.authorization-server.com
```

In short, you must add to your request header parameter Authorization with key "Bearer " + token you received.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you're using the `authorization code` flow obtaining the token. In this flow, first client/app request `auth code` from the `authorization server`. The server return the code in the redirect uri provided/configured for the app. The client then exchange this `auth code` with `access_token` by requesting the authorization server again.

The authorization code request usually have the following format

```
https://<authorization_server>/oauth/authorize
?client_id=<registered_client id with authorization server>
&response_type=code
&state=<nonce>
&redirect_uri=<redirection endpoint to receive the code>
```

Now, Your application needs to exchange the `auth code`, extracted in the previous stage, for an `access_token` to make API requests.

The request would be usually like the following one

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: <authroization server>

client_id=<registered_client id with authorization server>
&client_secret=<client seret obtained while registration>
&grant_type=code
&code=<code return in the previous request>
&redirect_uri=<redirection endpoint mentioned in the previous request>
```

A successful response from the code exchange request would be like the following.

```
{
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "access_token": "JDrM5knpv5YG0wTWnQbIqM75zdL80qmREsP2ucL4",
    "refresh_token": "v4YG0wTWnQbIqMoDrM5knp0qmREsP2ucL475zdL8",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Now, you can pass the previous obtained `access_token` in the header for making requests to `Resouce server`.

```
Authorization: Bearer JDrM5knpv5YG0wTWnQbIqM75zdL80qmREsP2ucL4
```